# Is there a free or cinematic camera?

Tags: baldurs-gate-3

Is it possible to get a free(r) camera or cinematic camera somehow?

It's obvious that the game contains quite some detailed 3D scenery, but it's hard to find a camera angle to actually get a good look at something, since zooming out always brings you into a top-down view. I would like the ability to look upwards.

Not only for the sake of pretty views, but also because in some battles, enemies have archers etc at strategic locations high up and if you aren't paying attention they are easy to miss.

I've checked keybindings but couldn't find anything that seemed to fit the bill.

Comment: There are mods on Nexus that purport to do this, but not having tried any myself, I'll leave it to someone with experience to provide an answer on that.

Comment: Worth noting here during battle you can click the turn order avatars at the top of the screen to view enemies out of your line of sight.